# How to implement a listView inside an ExpandableRelativeLayout?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I want to implement a `listView` inside `ExpandableRelativeLayout` but the `listview` doesn't scroll and the rest of the list can't be displayed. I want it to be something like the attached image, a `RecyclerView` above the `EditText` and a `ListView` below the `EditText` which is showed when user searches for a name.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, please consider adding some issue-related code for people to be able to help you, you may add what you have tried so far. also please take a look on [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyListView  extends ListView {

    public MyListView  (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyListView  (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListView  (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    } }
```

---

```
 <yourPackageName.MyListView
      android:id="@+id/lstsemtrack"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:divider="#f2e4e4"
      android:dividerHeight="1dip">
 </yourPackageName.ListView>
```

---

Please follow customListView which will take height based on content.

Comment: first thank you for your help, but my problem is that the expanableRelativelayout that contains all listview and recyclerview doesn't show all the elements contained inside